# Read Only access to GitHub repo via SSH key

Tags: ssh, github, ssh-keys

I want to generate an SSH key with only *READ* permissions to be used with my GitHub account is it possible? or should I create another account with only read permission?

Comment: The Deploy Key !

Comment: The Deploy key cannot be shared across multiple repositories at GH which may completely break the plan.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

#### [Deploy Keys to the rescue](https://blog.github.com/2015-06-16-read-only-deploy-keys/)

A deploy key is an **SSH key** that :

- is stored on your server and grants access to a single GitHub repository.
- Often used to clone repositories during deploys or continuous integration runs.
- Deploys sometimes involve merging branches and pushing code, so deploy keys **have always allowed both read and write access**.
- But Because write access is undesirable in many cases, you can have the ability to create deploy keys with read-only access.
- New deploy keys created through GitHub.com will be read-only by default and can be given write access by selecting `Allow write access` during creation.

#### Creating Read only deploy key

1. Go to `Settings` tab inside the repository you want to give read only permission.
2. On the left side navigation bar Select `Deploy Keys`

[image: Github Deploy Keys]

3. Click  <kbd>Add Deploy Key</kbd> .
4. Give it a title whatever you want and Add the ssh key.
5. Make sure that box `Allow write access` is unchecked.
6. You're done !

To know more about Deploy keys, read at **[Github Developer](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/)**. Also refer to this [beautiful gist](https://gist.github.com/zhujunsan/a0becf82ade50ed06115) by zhujunsan on Github.

Feel free to add-in more details.

Comment: And to add multiple repositories, generate one SSH key for each and add the configuration to the SSH config file as explained on https://medium.com/@dustinfarris/managing-multiple-github-deploy-keys-on-a-single-server-f81f8f23e473

Comment: but generating ssh keys for each repository deploy key is messy, lets say there are 10 repositories that I want to deploy to a machine.

Answer (score 22):

Github organizations can "sort of" support this work-flow:

- Create an organization
- Create a dummy account which will be used for readonly access
- Add the dummy account to the organization with read-only permissions
- Add whatever SSH keys you want to have on the read-only account
- Use your normal account(s) to allow writing

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, this one gives you read access to ALL repositories in the organization.

Comment: This seems to be "the" plan of GH, to force an additional user per company for such case because deploy keys cannot be shared among repositories?